# Alternatives to TAILS for anonimity on TOR unfriendly websites

Tags: encryption, linux, privacy, tor

I'm a happy TAILS user since a while. I've immeditaly fallen in love with the simplicity of the installation and user experience in general: no code, minimal competences required to get everything up and runniing, and next thing you know is that you are surfing the net anonymously with an encripted storage for your local files. Wonderful.

BUT

From time to time I get to very TOR unfriendly websites, who just don't let me in.

Be it an infinite sequence of google captcha, or just being excluded outright by their firewall, there's just no way to access them, let alone interact with them. Some for example would let me surf, but won't accept me subscribing to them.

I therefore started to think how to bypass the problem, and I finally decided to opt for NordVPN over a reasonably anonymous OS, with Firefox installed and all the privacy addons.

And here is my problem: what OS would I consider to be safe? Windows and iOS would be excluded outright, as they are basically software designed to collect your data and send them over to Cupertino and Redmond.

Linux would be my safest bet. The problem is that I can't find an easy way to get something like a:

- Portable
- Persistent
- Encrypted
- Non-TOR

Linux distro that can be combined with NordVPN with relative ease.

All my attempts have failed miserably so far. I basically experimented with Ubuntu, but to no avail.  When it comes to software installations is a nightmare, and I can't get past that point, especially when trying to get NordVPN installed to protect my traffic.

I then read somewhere that any new software needs to be adapted to the new Ubuntu release, and that's why most software just does not work unless highly personalized (excuse any nonsense here, as I said I ain't no Linux expert...).

In this case, I'd definitely say that rather having a wonderfully anonymous linux I prefer to follow as many privacy recommendations as possible, and have some kind of clean windows installation that I only use to navigate over NordVPN for as few interactions as possible with the outer world.

So, just to briefly recap: just assume all the rest is in place, no messing with multiple identities in the same place, an anonymous connection, etc. What would be your best advice to get an encrypted, portable, persistent, non-TOR OS?

Thanks for your contributions!!

Comment: You should be able to set up NordVPN on Ubuntu quite easily, what problems are you running into?

Comment: I just can't get past the stage of installing the files downloaded from NordVPN website. The fact is, whenever I look to NordVPN installation guide, I'm wondering the following: this is NOT just plug and play like in windows or MAC. I'm required to do quite a big coding effort which I do not understand. No doubts I can get past the complicated step of installing this whole thing (which will take an effort from my side). What guarantees to me that some weird mistake in setting up a killswitch or double VPN won't just leak IP some location data?? Isn't it better to go for something else?

Comment: while it doesn't have a GUI, you're basically just doing an install, just through the terminal. It's still quite plug and play.

Comment: I'll give it another try. You recommend installing the NordVPN app then, not using the network configuration with Open VPN? Thanks for your contribution, I forgot to mention yesterday :)

Comment: haha you're so polite. Either one works, using NordVPNs app might be a touch better because it's geared towards all the features NordVPN has.

Answer (score 0):

The runner up to Tails in terms of privacy and security is typically Qubes OS. You can set up a VPN connection on it by configuring it through the NetworkManager inside the NetVM. Qubes does not require all connections to be through Tor so you shouldn't have issues there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check that out!!